# Custom event receivers not recognised in a custom document set solution

Tags: document-set, document-library, content-type

I'm trying to do the following:

I need the Document Set functionality of 2010, and I need to be able to add event receivers when a new document set is added, and when a new document is added to the document set.

I also need some additional columns, so I need to create a custom content type for both the Document Set and the Document.

This should be a pretty straightforward job, but now I've spent more than two days, and still unable to create a Visual Studio solution with (sample code provided below):

- MyDocumentCT
- MyDocumentSetCT (with AllowedContentTypes MyDocumentCT)
- MyDocumentSetListDefinition (Based on MyDocumentSetCT)
- MyDocumentSetListInstance

I've tried several approaches, from building the xml by hand, to creating them in the web, and importing using vs import project. All of the leading to sln that don't behave like the default DocumentSet. (Icons missing, links not working, welcome page not showing...)

Does anyone have a sample describing this? This is the best link I've found: [Docset provisioning](http://www.sharepoint2010blog.nl/CommentView,guid,349d648e-9195-4d4c-872b-8183d0b4f359.aspx).

This is some start code if someone would like to have a look:

The MyDocumentCT (named BouvetDoc...)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x0101008881209E97CA44FEACC256CAC32CD7F7" Name="BouvetDoc" Group="Custom Content Types" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Folder TargetName="_cts/BouvetDoc" />
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" />
      <FieldRef ID="{5f47e085-2150-41dc-b661-442f3027f552}" Name="SelectFilename" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" Required="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}" Name="Created" Hidden="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Required="FALSE" ShowInNewForm="FALSE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f}" Name="Modified" Hidden="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9}" Name="Modified_x0020_By" Hidden="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb}" Name="Created_x0020_By" Hidden="FALSE" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>DocumentLibraryForm</Display>
          <Edit>DocumentLibraryForm</Edit>
          <New>DocumentLibraryForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

And here is MyDocumentSetCT (named BouvetDocSet...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Content Type" Sealed="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" Name="ContentTypeId" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <DisplayPattern>
      <MapToContentType>
        <Column Name="ContentTypeId" />
      </MapToContentType>
    </DisplayPattern>
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69}" Name="Created" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created" Group="_Hidden" ColName="tp_Created" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Created" StorageTZ="TRUE" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb}" Name="Created_x0020_By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Created_x0020_By" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Type="Text" DisplayName="Document Created By" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9}" Name="Modified_x0020_By" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Modified_x0020_By" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Type="Text" DisplayName="Document Modified By" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{960ff01f-2b6d-4f1b-9c3f-e19ad8927341}" Name="FolderChildCount" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FolderChildCount" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="Folder Child Count" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="FolderChildCount" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{b824e17e-a1b3-426e-aecf-f0184d900485}" Name="ItemChildCount" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ItemChildCount" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="Item Child Count" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="ItemChildCount" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f}" Name="Modified" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Modified" Group="_Hidden" ColName="tp_Modified" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="DateTime" DisplayName="Modified" StorageTZ="TRUE" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FileLeafRef" Group="_Hidden" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE" Type="File" DisplayName="Name" AuthoringInfo="(for use in forms)" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="LeafName" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Required="TRUE" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />
  <Field ID="{5f47e085-2150-41dc-b661-442f3027f552}" Name="SelectFilename" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="SelectFilename" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Select" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" AuthoringInfo="(web part connection)" HeaderImage="blank.gif" Sortable="FALSE" Overwrite="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1}" Name="ID" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <DisplayPattern>
      <IfEqual>
        <Expr1>
          <GetVar Name="SelectedID" />
        </Expr1>
        <Expr2>
          <Column Name="ID" />
        </Expr2>
        <Then>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<img align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/images/rbsel.gif" alt="]]></HTML>
          <HTML>Selected</HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
        </Then>
        <Else>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<a href="javascript:SelectField(']]></HTML>
          <GetVar Name="View" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[',']]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE">
            <Column Name="ID" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[');return false;" onclick="javascript:SelectField(']]></HTML>
          <GetVar Name="View" />
          <HTML><![CDATA[',']]></HTML>
          <ScriptQuote NotAddingQuote="TRUE">
            <Column Name="ID" />
          </ScriptQuote>
          <HTML><![CDATA[');return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[<img border="0" align="absmiddle" style="cursor: hand" src="/_layouts/images/rbunsel.gif"  alt="]]></HTML>
          <HTML>Normal</HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
          <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
        </Else>
      </IfEqual>
    </DisplayPattern>
  </Field>
  <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" Group="_Hidden" Type="Text" DisplayName="Title" Required="TRUE" FromBaseType="TRUE" Overwrite="FALSE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" />

  <ContentType ID="0x0120D52000AA321CBCA1F244AC9591CFFCE9A3E33B" Name="BouvetDocSet" Group="Custom Content Types" Overwrite="TRUE" ProgId="SharePoint.DocumentSet" PushDownChangedResourceFilesOnly="TRUE" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <Folder TargetName="_cts/BouvetDocSet" />
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" />
      <FieldRef ID="{b824e17e-a1b3-426e-aecf-f0184d900485}" Name="ItemChildCount" />
      <FieldRef ID="{960ff01f-2b6d-4f1b-9c3f-e19ad8927341}" Name="FolderChildCount" />
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" Required="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" />
      <FieldRef ID="{cbb92da4-fd46-4c7d-af6c-3128c2a5576e}" Name="Description" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/sharedfields">
        <SharedFields xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/sharedfields" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/defaultdocuments">
        <DefaultDocuments xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/defaultdocuments" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" AddSetName="" />
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields">
        <WelcomePageFields xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview">
        <WelcomePageView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
        <spe:Receivers xmlns:spe="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
          <Receiver>
            <Name>DocumentSet ItemUpdated</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10002</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>100</SequenceNumber>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSetEventReceiver</Class>
            <Data />
            <Filter />
          </Receiver>
          <Receiver>
            <Name>DocumentSet ItemAdded</Name>
            <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
            <Type>10001</Type>
            <SequenceNumber>100</SequenceNumber>
            <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
            <Class>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSetItemsEventReceiver</Class>
            <Data />
            <Filter />
          </Receiver>
        </spe:Receivers>
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/allowedcontenttypes">
        <act:AllowedContentTypes xmlns:act="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/allowedcontenttypes" LastModified="10/04/2010 12:41:27">
          <AllowedContentType id="0x0101008881209E97CA44FEACC256CAC32CD7F7" />
        </act:AllowedContentTypes>
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListForm</Display>
          <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
          <New>DocSetDisplayForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
        <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
          <New>_layouts/NewDocSet.aspx</New>
        </FormUrls>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Here is the MyDocumentSetListDefinition (named BouvetDocSetLD...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" Title="BouvetDocSetLD" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Bouvet.MiniDocCenter.SharePoint-BouvetDocSetLD" BaseType="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x0120D52000AA321CBCA1F244AC9591CFFCE9A3E33B" Name="BouvetDocSet" Group="Custom Content Types" Overwrite="TRUE" ProgId="SharePoint.DocumentSet" PushDownChangedResourceFilesOnly="TRUE">
        <Folder TargetName="_cts/BouvetDocSet" />
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" />
          <FieldRef ID="{b824e17e-a1b3-426e-aecf-f0184d900485}" Name="ItemChildCount" />
          <FieldRef ID="{960ff01f-2b6d-4f1b-9c3f-e19ad8927341}" Name="FolderChildCount" />
          <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" Required="FALSE" Hidden="TRUE" />
          <FieldRef ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" Required="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" />
          <FieldRef ID="{cbb92da4-fd46-4c7d-af6c-3128c2a5576e}" Name="Description" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE" />
        </FieldRefs>
        <XmlDocuments>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/sharedfields">
            <SharedFields xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/sharedfields" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/defaultdocuments">
            <DefaultDocuments xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/defaultdocuments" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" AddSetName="" />
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields">
            <WelcomePageFields xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepagefields" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview">
            <WelcomePageView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/welcomepageview" LastModified="1/1/1 0:00:01 AM" />
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
            <spe:Receivers xmlns:spe="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/events">
              <Receiver>
                <Name>DocumentSet ItemUpdated</Name>
                <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
                <Type>10002</Type>
                <SequenceNumber>100</SequenceNumber>
                <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                <Class>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSetEventReceiver</Class>
                <Data />
                <Filter />
              </Receiver>
              <Receiver>
                <Name>DocumentSet ItemAdded</Name>
                <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
                <Type>10001</Type>
                <SequenceNumber>100</SequenceNumber>
                <Assembly>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                <Class>Microsoft.Office.DocumentManagement.DocumentSets.DocumentSetItemsEventReceiver</Class>
                <Data />
                <Filter />
              </Receiver>
            </spe:Receivers>
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/allowedcontenttypes">
            <act:AllowedContentTypes xmlns:act="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/documentsets/allowedcontenttypes" LastModified="10/04/2010 12:41:27">
              <AllowedContentType id="0x0101008881209E97CA44FEACC256CAC32CD7F7" />
            </act:AllowedContentTypes>
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
            <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
              <Display>ListForm</Display>
              <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
              <New>DocSetDisplayForm</New>
            </FormTemplates>
          </XmlDocument>
          <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
            <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
              <New>_layouts/NewDocSet.aspx</New>
            </FormUrls>
          </XmlDocument>
        </XmlDocuments>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8}" Name="FileLeafRef" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FileLeafRef" Group="_Hidden" ShowInFileDlg="FALSE" ShowInVersionHistory="FALSE" Type="File" DisplayName="Name" AuthoringInfo="(for use in forms)" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="LeafName" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Required="TRUE" Overwrite="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{b824e17e-a1b3-426e-aecf-f0184d900485}" Name="ItemChildCount" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ItemChildCount" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="Item Child Count" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="ItemChildCount" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Overwrite="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{960ff01f-2b6d-4f1b-9c3f-e19ad8927341}" Name="FolderChildCount" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="FolderChildCount" Group="_Hidden" ReadOnly="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" Hidden="FALSE" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="Folder Child Count" List="Docs" FieldRef="ID" ShowField="FolderChildCount" JoinColName="DoclibRowId" JoinRowOrdinal="0" JoinType="INNER" Overwrite="TRUE" />
      <Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Content Type" Sealed="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" Overwrite="TRUE">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" Name="ContentTypeId" />
    </FieldRefs>
    <DisplayPattern>
      <MapToContentType>
        <Column Name="ContentTypeId" />
      </MapToContentType>
    </DisplayPattern>
  </Field>
      <Field ID="{CBB92DA4-FD46-4C7D-AF6C-3128C2A5576E}" Indexed="FALSE" Name="DocumentSetDescription" StaticName="DocumentSetDescription" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" Group="_Hidden" DisplayName="$Resources:dlccore,DocumentSetDescription_DisplayName;" Description="$Resources:dlccore,DocumentSetDescription_Description;" Type="Note" NumLines="5" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary="TRUE" Hidden="FALSE" Required="FALSE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Sealed="TRUE" />
    </Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Attachments">
          </FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle">
          </FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID">
            </FieldRef>
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across your post looking into issues with the XMLDocument node with SharePoint 2010.  Looking at what you have it may be related.  It seems as though the node either just doesn't/isn't meant to work with SharePoint 2010 or you need use a work around.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/daac5dee-a283-4c8f-8275-46b412688066?ppud=4

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I ended up with adding eventreceivers from code, but I also needed to set the Allowed contenttype from code.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by setting up the document set like you want it in the SharePoint UI, apart from the additional event receivers you require of course. Then save the site as a template (WSP file). Load this WSP into Visual Studio and only keep those artifacts relevant to your document set solution. Make sure everything deploys and works properly at this point. I've only ever had problems here if I've fiddled with the generated XML in some way so don't be tempted!

Then you need to add the event handlers. This is a known issue - we've already [had a question about it here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3810/xmldocuments-element-ignored-in-content-type). Read the link to TechNet that [Mark Z](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/5953/argghh-why-is-this-so-difficult-custom-documentset-with-custom-document-conte/6403#6403) gives to see if any of the suggestions there work. Assuming you find the solution, remember to come back here and tell us!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. Yes, it usually works if you don't mess with the xml after using the import wsp, but I'm pretty sure I tried that. I think the problem was related to the AllowdContenttype in the DocSet. But as I told Mark, I ended up doing it from code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Inherits attribute from your content type declaration. This will solve it.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! While this may theoretically answer the question, we prefer including more details in an answer. Perhaps include a small code sample or more explanation around why it is incorrect? See [How to Answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for general guidelines.